# Validar campo input de type file en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

estoy implementando un sistema de registro de mascotas, dentro del formulario también debe de enviar la foto de la mascota, me gustaría me ayuden con el código para validar que input no vaya vacío y que me debe de enviar un mensaje de error, también validar el tipo de archivos a subir como .jpg. png. Gracias.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger d-none" id="mensajeErrorFotoReg">
                Debe de seleccionar una foto de la mascota
 </div>

 <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-12">
                  <label for="foto-can">Foto de la mascota</label>
                  <div class="custom-file">
                    <input
                      data-toggle="tooltip"
                      data-placement="bottom"
                      title="Este campo es obligatorio"
                      type="file"
                      class="custom-file-input"
                      id="fotoMascotaRegistra"
                    />
                    <label
                      class="custom-file-label"
                      for="customFileLangHTML"
                      data-browse="Elegir archivo"
                      >* Seleccionar una foto</label
                    >
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

function fotoMascoRegis() 
 var mensajeErrorFotoReg = document.getElementById("mensajeErrorFotoReg");
 mensajeErrorFotoReg.classList.remove("d-none");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Podés usar el atributo `accept` del campo de entrada para limitar las opciones que el usuario podrá seleccionar en la ventana de selección de archivo. Asimismo, podés implementar una lógica de comparación de la extensión del archivo que el usuario seleccionó contra la lista de extensiones que especificaste en el atributo `accept` del campo:

```js
function validar() {
  // Obtener nombre de archivo
  let archivo = document.getElementById('archivo').value,
  // Obtener extensión del archivo
      extension = archivo.substring(archivo.lastIndexOf('.'),archivo.length);
  // Si la extensión obtenida no está incluida en la lista de valores
  // del atributo "accept", mostrar un error.
  if(document.getElementById('archivo').getAttribute('accept').split(',').indexOf(extension) < 0) {
    alert('Archivo inválido. No se permite la extensión ' + extension);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="archivo" type="file" accept=".jpg,.png" required onchange="validar()" />
```

Agregué el atributo required para que el campo no pueda ir vacío, según la sugerencia de DjCrazy

Comment: Y como haría para que me envié un error cuando esta vació..

Comment: y si a eso le agregas el atributo `required`, el formulario no se va si el campo está vacío.

Comment: Bueno utilice con required, pero es de html5, la cosa es validarlo con javascript, les pido me ayuden, les pido analicen en código, gracias.

Comment: Actualicé el ejemplo con la validación de JS. Únicamente debés obtener la extensión del archivo y compararla con la lista de archivos válidos en el campo "accept". De esa forma, no hay duplicidad de lógica y al agregar un tipo de archivo aceptado, automáticamente el JS valida contra él.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono, un fuerte abrazo muchas gracias..

Comment: Si mi respuesta solucionó tu problema, marcala cómo respuesta para que le sirva a otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

**Intenta esto**, el siguiente script obtiene el nombre del archivo en cuando es seleccionado, después valida que sea un archivo correcto en caso de serlo obtiene la extensión y posteriormente valida que dicha extensión este dentro de las permitidas.

```
$(document).ready( function (){
 $('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
        //obtiene el nombre del archivo seleccionado
        var filename = $("#file_input").val();
        //si es null muestra un mensaje de error
        if(filename == null)
             alert('No ha seleccionado una imagen');
        else{// si se eligio un archivo correcto obtiene la extension para vlidarla
             var extension = filename.replace(/^.*\./, '');               

             if (extension == filename)
                 extension = '';
             else{
                 extension = extension.toLowerCase();
                 //aqui puedes incluir todas las extensiones que quieres permitir
                 if((extension != 'jpg') || (extension != 'png') || 
                    (extension != 'jpeg'))
                    alert("extencion no valida");
           }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pasar la ruta de la variable que llega y así funciona bien.

```javascript
let extension = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('.'), url.length);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).